# Merge multiple document categorizer models in OpenNLP

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, opennlp

I am trying to write a map-reduce implementation of Document Categorizer using OpenNLP.

During the training phase, I am planning to read a large amount of files and create a model file as result of the map-reduce computation(may be a chain of jobs). I will distribute the files to different mappers, I would create a number of model files as result of this step. Now, I wish to reduce these model files to a single model file to be used for classification.

I understand that this is not the most intuitive of use cases, but I am ready to get my hands dirty and extend/modify the OpenNLP source code, assuming it is possible to tweak the maxent algorithm to work this way.

In case this seems too far fetched, I request for suggestions to do this by generating document samples corresponding to the input files as output of map-reduce step and reducing them to model files by feeding them to document categorizer trainer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before, and my approach was to not have each reducer produce the model, but rather only produce the properly formatted data. 
Rather than use a category as a key, which separates all the categories   Just use a single key and make the value the proper format (cat sample newline)  then in the single reducer you can read in that data as (a string) a bytearrayinputstream and train the model.  Of course this is not the only way. You wouldn't have to modify opennlp at all to do this.

Simply put, my recommendation is to use a single job that behaves like this:

Map: read in your data, create category label and sample pair. Use a key called 'ALL' and context.write each pair with that key .

Reduce: use a stringbuilder to concat all the cat: sample pairs into the proper training format. Convert the string into a bytearrayinputstream and feed the training API . Write the model somewhere.

Problem may occur that your samples data is too huge to send to one node. If so, you can write the values to A nosql db and read then in from a beefier training node. Or you can use randomization in your mapper to produce many keys and build many models, then at classification time write z wrapper that tests data across them all and Getz The best from each one..... Lots of options.
HTH

Comment: The issue with my use case is that I will get millions of files to be categorized each day. And I want the system to get better with each passing day by relearning all the samples during off-peak hours and hence, generate a fresh model file with all the existing and newly received data.

Comment: are you doing the classification on an incoming stream, or is that happening in batch as well? if the latter, then I recommend writing out the model to something like HBase or a file to be used in the distributed cache, so you can run the job to build the model, then run another job that uses the newly created model on disk. It's also not a bad idea to keep versions of the model, in case you've trained it so much it begins to over fit.... just some thoughts.

Comment: I am focussing primarily on batch processing. I am thinking of training the model periodically through cron jobs with all the data received till now. Untill this new model is ready, I will use the older model.

Comment: During the training job, having a single key and hence a single reducer node may get impossible as the days pass by and I want to steer away from having this dependent on a single beefy node. I am inclining towards the use of randomization and generate multiple models. Won't this affect accuracy of the classifier because of distributed independent variables?

Comment: it will, but if you manage the amount of categories that each mapper can emit to each random bucket, you could probably do ok. Also, since at classification time you will essentially loop over a set of models, maintain the best score for each category across all the models it will do pretty well. I used this technique once doing clustering, I used a Map<Integer, Integer> at the class level of my mapper class, where the key is the bucket number, and the value is the amount of items I emited with that key, so once a map task filled up a key, i would start using the other key etc. Your key=a cat

Comment: Awesome! I see how that would improve the accuracy by having at least some representation of each category in every model file. I hope this solves my problem. I should do a little proof of concept before going to production though I know it worked well for you. I am also contemplating use of Mahout for the task, I chose OpenNLP because of it's accuracy. Do you have experience with Mahout for doing this kind of a task?

Comment: no, never used mahout for classification. let me know how it goes!